# Sample simpleHangoutApp.xml file not read

Tags: asp.net, iis, google-hangouts

Can I run the `google +Hangout` application in my local PC. I have download the `simpleHangoutApp.xml` file and publish on local PC `IIS` server. when I browse(in Firefox) it displays only `XML` tags. Could you please tell me how to publish `+hangout` app in local PC `IIS` Server.

Answer (score 0):

The Hangout App needs to run on the Google servers inside a Hangout. In order to publish your app, follow the instructions on the [Google+ Developer](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/publishing) site.